# Confusion with analog input range spec from a manual

Tags: analog, datasheet, manual

Looking at [this](https://www.thorlabs.com/drawings/1713729ad7306cb5-18E94DB7-F557-AE61-578B250A377F22C6/GVS112-Manual.pdf) manual of a galvo-mirror device, I'm confused with relating the analog inputs to angle range. It is written in the manual:

```
The scanner accepts a differential analog command input. If the scaling is 0.5 Volt per
degree mechanical movement (see Section 3.2.5.), -10 V to +10 V gives -20 to +20
degrees mechanical movement. The driver will attempt to set the mirror position to the
command input value.
```

Here is what I am confused about: Lets focus on one of the galvo-mirror which requires diff bipolar inputs to rotate the mirror. And lets call the bipolar diff inputs as Vp and Vn where Vdiff = Vp-Vn.

When they say "-10 V to +10 V gives -20 to +20 degrees", is -10 and +10 meant for (Vp-Vn) or simply Vp? This confuses me, because if the -10 V to +10 V range is meant for Vidff=(Vp-Vn) then the range for Vp will be -5 to +5 and the range for Vn will be +5 to -5. But if the -10 V to +10 V range is meant for Vp, then the range for Vp will be -10 to +10 and the range for Vn will be +10 to -10 which means Vdiff will swing from -20V to +20V.

Can someone help me what is meant by inputs here?

Answer (score 2):

With differential inputs, this means (Vp - Vn).

The input is differential, so this could mean that the range of Vp and Vn are -5 to +5...It could also mean that Vn is always zero and Vp can be -10 V to +10 V.  It depends on the other aspects of that input what is allowed.